# jquery code working fine in firefox but giving error in IE "object expected error line 1 char 1"

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

This code working fine in FF but giving error in IE

```
object expected error line 1 char 1
```

jquery code

```
$(function () {
    $('#header_images img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#header_images :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#header_images');
    }, 3000);
});
```

this is added in external.js file.

**Edit: 7 September**

This is how i added the JavaScript in `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

This code which i added in question , is in `script.js` as it is

Comment: Have you tried enabling IE8's debugger?  If not, you should definitely try that.

Comment: What do your `<script>` tags look like?  It sounds like jQuery may not be included correctly in the page, or another script tag screws up everything beneath it.

Comment: @Nick Craver - but this error only coming in IE

Comment: gear-solid - Different browsers handle invalid HTML in different ways...

Comment: @Nick Craver - I added my js links in question

Answer (score 0):

this is how I'm using similar code without any issues:

```
$(function() {
            $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function(){
              $('#slideshow :first-child').fadeOut('slow')
                 .next('img').fadeIn('slow')
                 .end().appendTo('#slideshow');}, 
              4000);
});
```

Comment: mine has an extra semi-colon. can you replace your code with mine and try?

Comment: also is this the only code you have in your dom ready? it could something before this.

Comment: Now i'm using this `$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
            $('#header_images img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function(){
              $('#header_images :first-child').fadeOut('slow')
                 .next('img').fadeIn('slow')
                 .end().appendTo('#header_images');}, 
              4000);
});
});`
 but error still here